# How to select a decimal number from a mySQL float column

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table with a column, 'field_number', of type float. Many of its rows contain the number, 357.1. Using phpmyadmin's SQL window, I seem to be completely unable to select that value.

```
SELECT *  FROM  `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE  `field_number` =  357.1
```

Doesn't work.

```
SELECT *  FROM  `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE  `field_number` =  '357.1'
```

Doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM  `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE  `field_number` LIKE  '%357%'
```

Does work, yet I need to be precise because other rows my contain 357.2 or other similar value.

And just to be sure it has something to do with the decimal number ...

```
SELECT * FROM  `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE  `field_number` =356
```

Works. There must be something simple I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, I'll check out the linked answer.

Comment: `SELECT *  FROM  wp_rg_lead_detail  WHERE CAST(  field_number AS DECIMAL ) = CAST( 357.1 AS DECIMAL )`  Works.